# In a comma delimited String, keep all but second part

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of addresses:

```
123 Main Street, PO Box 345, Chicago, IL 92921
1992 Super Way, Bakersfield, CA
234 Wonderland Lane, Attn: Daffy Duck, Orlando, FL 09922
```

How could I cut out the second string in there, when I do `myStr.split(',')` on each?

The idea is that I want to return:

```
123 Main Street, Chicago, IL 92921
1992 Super Way, CA
234 Wonderland Lane, Orlando, FL 09922
```

I could loop through each part, and build yet another string, skipping the second index, but was wondering if there's a better way to do so.

What I have now:

```
def filter_address(address):
    print("Filtering address on",address)
    updated_addr = ""
    indx = 0
    for section in address.split(","):
        if indx != 1:
            updated_addr = updated_addr + "," + section
        indx += 1
    updated_addr = updated_addr[1:]  # This is to remove the leading `,`

new_address = filter_address("123 Main Street, Chicago, IL 92921")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `del` in python and glue back the components of the string with ", " after splitting them.

For example:

```py
address = "123 Main Street, PO Box 345, Chicago, IL 92921".split(",")
del address[1]
pretty_address = ", ".join(address)

print(pretty_address) # Gives 123 Main Street,  Chicago,  IL 92921
```

Comment: Oh, that's great!  Simple, neat and clear.  Cheers!!